# Can the Vim tabularize plugin match multiple expressions per column?

Tags: vim, plugins, alignment

I'd like to use the vim tabularize plugin to align the following type of code:

```
buy <- blabla   
buy[,cash := blablabla]
pr.tmp <- matrix(blaaaaaaaaa)
```

to read as follows:

```
buy       <- blabla 
buy[,cash := blablabla]
pr.tmp    <- matrix(blaaaaaaaaa)
```

My question is if tabularize can match "<-" AND ":=" in the SAME COLUMN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use branches:

```
:Tabularize /<-\|:=/
```

See `:help \|`